# Weird crash while installing to iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, titanium

I have developed an iPad application, It runs fine in simulator but when I try to install it on device, it crashes with `Segmentation fault: 11`

Here are the Titanium environment details:

**Application type**: mobile

**Titanium SDK**: 1.8.3 (04/18/12 10:48 6c2fca1)

**Platform & version**: iOS 5.0

**Device**: physical iPad device (with iOS 5.0.1 (9A405))

**Host Operating System**: OSX 10.6.8

**Titanium Studio**: 2.0.1

I still unable to debug this issue as there are no logs/errors are shown in Titanium console, It just does not get installed.

When I try to install it via XCode, this is what I get in organiser console `Segmentation fault: 11`

```
May 24 03:44:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: lockbot[2021] Builtin profile: gputoolsd (sandbox)
May 24 03:44:44 unknown ReportCrash[2027] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process installd[2025]
May 24 03:44:44 unknown mobile_installation_proxy[2026] <Error>: handle_install: Installation failed
May 24 03:44:44 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.mobile.installd) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
May 24 03:44:44 unknown ReportCrash[2027] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/xxxx using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

XCode also prompts with

```
"There was an internal API error."
```

**UPDATE**

It is not a certificate error as it builds successfully with XCode. The error is only seen while installing.

Comment: Try updating to Titanium SDK 2.0

Comment: just started getting this problem using ios-sim...

Answer (score 0):

I've raise a bug with ios-sim. will fix myself later if no one does prior

https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim/issues/25

Comment: Hey Hi, I am using Titanium not Phonegap